# How do i define a component inside what may be a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, accordion, react-bootstrap

i am new to react can anyone help, I am trying to use accordion to display a registration page i built, the page has four different fields, one for uploading of pictures, the second for address, the third for general information and the fourth for pricing, now here is the challenge.... I want to use accordion to define each field so that the field doesnt just appear as a long form, but you would need to click the field for it to display.... I have gotten pretty much everything right, i got stuck in how to place my components inside the accordion body....Note, I am using a bootstrap template.... Here is the code.

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header> Photo </Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      <PhotoUploader />
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
    <Accordion.Header>General information</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      <GeneralInfo />
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="2">
    <Accordion.Header>Address</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      <AddLocation />
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="3">
    <Accordion.Header> Pricing </Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      <AddPrice />
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

Where `<PhotoUploader/>`  , `<GeneralInfo/>` , `<AddLocation/>` ,  `<AddPrice/>` are my field components. I know how i placed them in is wrong, please whats the correct method.

Comment: So basically, I find the placement of the components correctly, why do you think you misplaced them?

Comment: Well, because if it were correct, it should work on my live server, but it's not working.. I double checked and I am a bit certain there's no other thing wrong except for the components.... I tried replacing the components with just <p></> and it works, but when I change it to the component, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess a better approach is to isolate some of the related component and create a sandbox so that you can share with others. This way, we can debug more effectively. especially now that from the looks of it, it seems like a find code.

Comment: Not to Worry, I resulted to using Tabs, inplace of an accordion and it displayed just fine!